# How much can I learn about 5e Neverwinter in a week?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms

We're talking the city here in case that's not clear.

Background: first-time DM, playing the Lost Mines start adventure with my 3 kids. They decide to head to Thundertree last week (pursuing that Druid adventure hook). After some adventures along the way last week, they are considering stopping off at Neverwinter on the way to Thundertree - they are currently about a day away from either one. I know nothing about Neverwinter.

---

So - I read through the Wikia FAQ. I don't consider that enough background to steep me in this city's "lore". **I have time to buy and read about 300 pages (give or take a hundred) between now and our next session.** Note that I find fiction to be just as good as non-fic for getting the feel of a place. Not really looking for dry facts, just story that I can mentally reference as I describe them riding into the city, meeting people, etc.

Should I buy Salvatore's Neverwinter Drizzt book from 2011? Or the Neverwinter Campaign Setting book? Or perhaps the Grand History of the Realms? Read subsections of two of these? Read another reference online?

Help me get the most out of ~300 pages of reading on Neverwinter!

Comment: There's no right answer to this question as it's currently written, so it's not the kind of question we answer here. You might be looking for a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of a Stack Exchange site, which works differently from a discussion forum.

Comment: You can learn about 7 in a week